# How to fix etcd cluster misconfigured error

Tags: coreos, etcd

Have two servers : `pg1: 10.80.80.195` and `pg2: 10.80.80.196`

Version of etcd :

```
etcd Version: 3.2.0
Git SHA: 66722b1
Go Version: go1.8.3
Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

I'm trying to run like this :

pg1 server :

```
etcd --name infra0 --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://10.80.80.195:2380   --listen-peer-urls http://10.80.80.195:2380   --listen-client-urls http://10.80.80.195:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379   --advertise-client-urls http://10.80.80.195:2379   --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1   --initial-cluster infra0=http://10.80.80.195:2380,infra1=http://10.80.80.196:2380   --initial-cluster-state new
```

pg2 server :

```
etcd --name infra1 --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://10.80.80.196:2380   --listen-peer-urls http://10.80.80.196:2380   --listen-client-urls http://10.80.80.196:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379   --advertise-client-urls http://10.80.80.196:2379   --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1   --initial-cluster infra0=http://10.80.80.195:2380,infra1=http://10.80.80.196:2380   --initial-cluster-state new
```

When trying to cherck health state on `pg1`:

```
etcdctl cluster-health
```

have an error :

```
cluster may be unhealthy: failed to list members
Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: client: endpoint http://127.0.0.1:2379 exceeded header timeout
; error #1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: getsockopt: connection refused

error #0: client: endpoint http://127.0.0.1:2379 exceeded header timeout
error #1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: getsockopt: connection refused
```

What I'm doing wrong and how to fix it ?
Both servers run on virtual machines with **Bridged Adapter**

Answer (score -1):

I've got similar error when I set up etcd clusters using systemd according to the [official tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#generate-etcd-client-certs) from kubernetes.

It's three centos 7 of medium instances on AWS. I'm pretty sure the security groups are correct. And I've just:

```
$ systemctl restart network
```

and the

```
$ etcdctl cluster-health
```

just gives a healthy result.

Comment: This does nothing to the existing issue of the etcd cluster being unhealthy. Is there some intermediate step that is missing that enables the etcd cluster to function normally?